# Is this a denormalized table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure but is this a denormalized table?

**EmployeesGrade**
EmpID
Grade1
Grade2
Grade3

If yes, how do make this a normalized table?

Comment: Any time you find a series of columns with numbered names (e.g., `Grade1, Grade2, Grade3`), that's a good clue that you're looking at a denormalized structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be denormalised. To normalise you would structure it as

```
EmpID
GradeNo
Grade
```

with EmpID and GradeNo as the primary key. Example records would then be:

```
EmpID   GradeNo Grade
-----   ------- -----
123     1       A
123     2       B
123     3       A
234     1       D
...
```